# In Typescript, why is calling a union of functions not a type error?

Tags: typescript, union-types

This code works, but I feel that it shouldn't. The `higherOrder` function should complain that `f` may only need one argument, but we're passing two.

```
type F1 = (a: number, b: number) => number;
type F2 = (a: number) => number;
type F = F1 | F2;

const f1: F1 = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;
const f2: F2 = (a: number) => 2 * a;

const higherOrder = (f: F): number => {
  return f(2, 3);
}

const result1 = higherOrder(f1);
const result2 = higherOrder(f2);
console.log(result1, result2);
```

Why are there no compiler errors? Playground link: [[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgjFAvFAFAQwFxQHYFcC2ARhAE4A0UhWeRpAlEgHw4HEkDcAUKJLAExJUmFrRINEzGmy49oMQfCgAffl04BjAPbYAzsCgAzOFkXJ01VqQpURbcczRQA1JS5bd+g3xMCzwqfRMUAIAVFBoau56UAAWAJYA5jGkAPIkACakgigGJnQWokEA3pxQUCQQwLgk2IYofBQAzHRcAL6cGtrRFTq4ADbACMjxSakZpDlwLZ0e5RC9A76xickkaZkkOXzTUZp9EAB0fZoJKD39gxTniy1AA)]

Comment: in either case you are passing something of type F

Comment: It doesn't have *much* to do with unions, you could replace `F` with `F1` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3v9yN) and have the same effect.  If TS knows for sure that you are calling a one-param func with two args it will complain, but it considers such a call *type safe* because the function will almost certainly just ignore it. So it allows assignments because it enables common uses like `[1].map(x => x.toFixed())`.  See [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters). (more...)

Comment: (...continued) does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does! Thanks so much. I figured that it was because the JS usecase is completely safe, the same functionality had been built into TS. Thanks again for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript takes the position that a function of fewer parameters is assignable to a function of more parameters, as described in [the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) and [the TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).  As such, your `F2` type is assignable to `F1`, and therefore the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `F1 | F2` is equivalent to just `F1`.  Indeed nothing changes if we use `F1` instead of `F1 | F2`, so we can dispense with talk of unions and just look at `F1`:

```
const higherOrder = (f: F1): number => { return f(2, 3); }
const result1 = higherOrder(f1); // okay
const result2 = higherOrder(f2); // okay
```

It is considered type safe to call a function with more arguments than it expects, since it is very likely that such a function will simply ignore the excess arguments.  As a convenience, the compiler will warn if it catches you actually making such a call *directly*:

```
const f1: F1 = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;
f1(2, 3); // okay

const f2: F2 = (a: number) => 2 * a;
f2(2, 3); // error
```

That error doesn't prevent any sort of runtime error, but it does possibly indicate a confusion on the part of the caller, so it is a warning.  But TypeScript allows you to *assign* a function of type `F2` to a value of type `F1`, and therefore you can make such a call *indirectly*:

```
const fOne: F1 = f2; // okay
fOne(2, 3); // okay
```

This is also for convenience.  Quite often when people pass a function as a callback, they don't give it as many parameters as the expected arguments it will be called with.  Functional array methods are a common example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(x => x + 1); // okay
```

The [`map()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will end up calling its callback with three arguments: the element, the index, and the whole array.  If it were an error to make the assignment of `F2` to `F1`, then it would also be an error to make the assignment of `x => x + 1` to the array callback, and you'd be forced to write something like

```
[1, 2, 3].map((x, i, arr) => x + 1);
```

which introduces `i` and `arr` for no discernible reason.

---

TypeScript doesn't intend to provide a perfectly consistent type system (see [TS Non-Goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #3); instead it tries to issue warnings in situations which are more likely to be mistakes and suppresses them in situations which are more likely to be intentional.  Calling a function directly with more arguments than necessary is more likely to be a mistake, so you get a warning.  Assigning a function to a place which is likely to call it with more arguments than necessary is more likely to be intentional, so you don't get a warning.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgjFAvFAFAQwFxQHYFcC2ARhAE4A0UhWeRpAlEgHw4HEkDcAUKJLAExJUmFrRINEzGmy6cAxgHtsAZ2BQAZnCzxB6aq1IUqItuOZooAakpcNKPhQDMdGQuWq1fLQOS7j9JlACAFRQaDZ8do7OUAD0MVCkJPIknHKKKuoA8tgQWgjIHuyx8fIA1mggnGrZEJFQTkVxUGUVqa4ZABYAlgDmHaSZJAAmpDpqeXR6ogEA3lAkEMC4JNjqdQ1QAL5pbvMQSrgANsD5UN19A8OkKBrRTS2V7aoLB8feZ739JIMjJDd8dxK5Ue6XkhwgADpDvIeigXkcThR4W9nKkANpwCj2eoAXQh+DQYBQAA8AqSrHBURisY48QSiSSKF0KGgSGIyZYoJT2EA)